# How to update textblock text of an inactive window from main window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two windows; main window and a sub window. I need to update some text in a textblock which is on sub window. But the text is not updates, when I put that textblock on main window, it updates the text.

I tried the following code:

Main Window QPlayer.XAML (Active Window)

```
<Window x:Class="AlQuran.Views.QPlayer"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:AlQuran.ViewModel"
        Width="300" Height="306" WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" AllowsTransparency="True" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Resources/AlQuran_Window.png"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:QuranViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid >
                <Image x:Name="BtnPlay" Grid.Column="0" MouseDown="BtnPlay_MouseDown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="79" Height="79">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/BtnPlay.png"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Resources/BtnPlay_Over.png"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                    <Image.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Play_Btn, Mode=OneTime}" />
                    </Image.InputBindings>
                </Image>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding TxtAyah, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Background="#FF38ECEC" FontSize="16" />
```

Info Window AyahWindow.xaml (Inactive window)

```
<Window x:Class="AlQuran.Views.AyahWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AlQuran"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:AlQuran.ViewModel"
        Width="900" Height="630"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" Opacity=".94" AllowsTransparency="True" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ViewModel:QuranViewModel x:Key="QViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:QuranViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid >
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            Text="{Binding TxtAyah, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            x:Name="AyahLine" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="#FFF51E1E" 
            FontFamily="Futura Md BT" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>
```

InfoWindow AyahWindow.XAML.CS (Inactive)

```
        public InfoWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string txt;
        public InfoWindow(string txt)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TxtToShow.Text = txt;
        }
```

ViewModel Class QuranViewModel.CS

```
namespace AlQuran.ViewModel
{
    public class QuranViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ICommand Play_Btn { get; set; }

        public QuranViewModel()
        {
            Play_Btn = new RelayCommand(PlayMethod, CanExecuteMyMethod);
        }

        private string _txtAyah;

        public string TxtAyah
        {
            get { return _txtAyah; }
            set { _txtAyah = value; OnPropertyChanged("TxtAyah"); }
        }

        private void PlayMethod(object parameter)
        {
            TxtAyah =new Random().Next(5,999999).ToString() ;

            AyahWindow aw = new AyahWindow(TxtAyah);
            aw.txt = TxtAyah;

        }

    }
}
```

Please help,  I am really stuck at this point.

and here is my project image to get better understanding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YEN6.png)

Comment: Only reason for this would be that sub windows needs focus to be updated using Ui thread, so if you can bring that to focus, then it shall work as expected. You can use `Dispatcher.Invoke` for the same

Comment: Could you provide a full working example ?  What do you mean by InfoWindoiw interactive ?

Comment: It will work without the focus switching. First the `Binding.Mode` of `TextBox` is `TwoWay` by default. Are you sure that you assigned the same `ProjViewModel` instance to the `Datacontext` of `InfoWindow`?

Comment: You have to create an object of `ProjViewModel` in the resources of App.xaml. Than bind the `DataContext` of both `Window` controls to it. It is importamt that the view model is shared between both windows.

Comment: I have edited and updated my question. Please review.

Comment: At last it is working.
I added a line

```
aw.DataContext = this.DataContext;
```

  In main window QPlayer.XAML.CS, like this:
```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AyahWindow aw = new AyahWindow();
            aw.Show();
            aw.DataContext = this.DataContext;
        } 
```

Thanks every on for for helping me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

And never handle view controls or classes in you view model. Create and show the `InfoWindow` from the buttons's event handler from your code-behind.
**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ProjViewModel}">
  <Grid>
      <Button Click="ShowWindow_OnClick"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding TextToShow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWndow
{
    private void ShowWindow_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      new InfoWindow().Show();
    }
}
```

**InfoWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="InfoWindow" 
        DataContext="{StaticResource ProjViewModel}">
  <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextToShow}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml:**

View model:

```
class ProjViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProjViewModel()
    {
    }

    private string _texttoshow;
    public string TextToShow
    {
        get { return _txttoshow; }
        set { _txttoshow= value; OnPropertyChanged("TxtToShow"); }
    }
}
```